# What is the ideal weapon for an Infiltrator/Spy Character?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons

I'm looking for a weapon type befitting an Infiltrator/Spy Character whose primary focus would be gathering information and getting in and out of places unnoticed.

What I am looking for is something that fulfils the following points:

- easily concealable
- can be used for melee and ranged combat
- can be easily replaced
- if possible has a range longer than 10 feet
- not a specific magic weapon

Comment: Are you looking for a weapon type, or a specific magic item? And do you have some more info on your character?

Comment: This is just asking for ideas and provides nothing to base objective, or experience-based subjective, answers on. It's both unclear and primarily opinion-based. (It might still be primarily opinion-based with more information, but that's impossible to tell without more information.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Unstated, but apparently something more esoteric than a **dagger** =  *What I am looking for is something that's easily concealable, can be used for melee and range, can be easily replaced, and if possible has a range longer than 10 feet.*

Answer (score 1):

**Thanks to the way the game math of Pathfinder works, there is no weapon that is both useful past very early levels *and* easily-replaced.** Even masterwork weapons cost a significant chunk of cash, and that makes them not easily-replaceable.

In order to find an offensive combat option that fits your specifications, you have to look elsewhere.

#### Spells

Spells replenish each day, can be used at melee and range, are easily concealed (simply don't use them), and often have long ranges. Given that there are no weapons that fit the specifications outlined in the question, and the implicit assumption that "befitting" means "useful for," rather than "merely an aesthetic choice for," you will need to branch into spellcasting.